# Perl equivalent to python's `setup.py develop`

Tags: module, installation, perl

Is there a Perl equivalent to the python `setup.py develop` convention for installing a module that can also be actively developed?

If not, what is the best practice for active development on a Perl module that is also installed into a local library path (for example a path setup using [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ehaarg/local-lib-2.000015/lib/local/lib.pm))?

I am just starting to make a module, so I will be developing the installation package (Makefile.PL etc.) alongside the meat of the module, and wondering what is the best way to set up the development environment. There are many good [tutorials](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235647/http://mathforum.org/ken/perl_modules.html) about making a module using `h2xs` or other tools, but I have not seen this question addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The `blib` core module sets up the include paths to use the `blib` directory structure that's created when you do `make` in a standard module directory. That way you can easily use your new code in scripts by running them with `perl -Mblib foo.pl`.

Another, arguably better, way is to write your test code while developing as standard test scripts and run them via the `prove` script. See the documentation on `Test::Simple` for how to get started on that.

Comment: Just checking, for first option, this requires running `make` before using the changed code, is that right? And I'm guessing `prove` is similar (or part of) running a `make test`?

Comment: Yes (if you don't want to even do that, `perl -Ilib` works most of the time). `prove` is a more developer-friendly way to do `make test` or parts of it. `perldoc prove` tells you more.

Comment: If you want to pull from _blib_, i suggest the command line `make && perl -Mblib ,,,` so every run picks up any new changes. I'd had plenty of experiences wondering why the tests are still failing even though I updated the code. But, if it never makes it to _blib_, you're running the old stuff that's there :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing XS stuff where you have to actually rebuild things and produce build artifacts, you can use `perl -Ilib ...`. This assumes that your `lib` directory is structured as it will be installed (but then, if it's not, you're rebuilding to produce build artifacts :).

If you are playing with this module in development from outside its directory structure:

```
$ perl -I/path/to/module/repo/lib ...
```

Or many of the other ways to set `@INC`:

```
$ export PERL5LIB=/path/to/module/repo/lib
$ perl some_program.pl
```

I typically don't use `prove` or `make` while developing because I'm concentrating on one test file at a time:

```
$ perl -Ilib t/some_test.t
```

When I think I've fixed the issue, I then try it against all the tests:

```
$ make test
```